Express router and controllers in different files
I am considering using Express as backend framework for new full stack application I develop.
The application is going to be quite big, and I would like to keep the logic separated in different controllers (following the MVC design pattern).
Is it possible to have in Express something like rotuer in one file, and login in other files?

Sure, why should this not be possible? Thats up to you how you structure you application.

I assume you want separation of concern and have different folders/files for routes, controllers, and services. It is indeed possible with node and express. Here is an example of code structure that I have seamlessly used for production level applications: link

Routes and other application-specific logic can live in as many files as you wish.
You may be able to find more about it in the FAQ section of Expressjs's official documentation. Please see to the link How should I structure my application?
